# Stacking two Dell PowerConnect 6248's: do I need one or two cables?

Tags: switch, dell, dell-powerconnect

I'm planning on stacking Dell PowerConnect 6248 switches together.  I know that I need one stacking module in each switch, but I'm uncertain about the cabling.  Since I only have two switches, do I need to loop them using two cables or will one stacking cable suffice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could get away with one. However unlikely, but possible, losing a stacking module would sever the connection between switches, and isolate the stacking function from one another. A second interconnect would provide redundancy, and possibly increased bandwidth between stack members.

This whitepaper has some good information about stacking:
[Stacking Dell PowerConnect 6200 Series Switches](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pwcnt/en/pwcnt_stacking_switches.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, I'm referring to the cables, not the modules.  Each module has two ports and each switch can contain two modules (4 ports/cables).

Answer (score 0):

One cable will work since it is bidirectional transmission, but you won't have any redundancy in this case. This is what @mcmeel meant (he never mentioned using a second module in the other bay, he spoke about interconnects).

Using n>1 cables between the stacking modules of both switches or even multiple stacking modules in each switch enables you to use Link Aggregation according to IEEE 802.1AX-2008, which offers you two big features:

- Redundancy: If a cable fails (which is more likely then ones might think), you have still an intact second route for your packets/data to flow. If you even have multiple stacking modules (both module bays occupied), you have redundancy in case an entire module fails.
- Speed: Depending on the load balancing algorithms of the switches, it is possible to achieve higher data rates, because the packets are distributed over the n interconnections. This results in higher throughput through the Link Aggregation Group compared to a single interconnection